# Bootstrap 5 Modal does not work properly on scroll, after adding some content dynamically - which cause Modal's height exceeds than earlier

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, scrollbar, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

Bootstrap 5 Modal does not work properly on scroll, after adding some content dynamically - which cause Modal's height exceeds than earlier.

Let me explain!

1. I opened a Bootstrap Modal by clicking on the 'Add Make' button.
2. Modal just appeared properly, and it have a form having up to 5 inputs.

[See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgqA5.png)

> Note: Still modal is working properly on scroll.

3. Now I just entered values in these inputs. And there are 2 inputs of type 'file', which I am using to upload a Image (One for 'icon' and Other one is for 'thumbnail'). And I am also showing these images underneath each of this input of type file. Which is a  kind of preview box for me to show that Image which is going to be uploaded.
4. As that preview box is hidden by default. And when we select a file then that preview box appears with the selected image.

[See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAxIS.png)

> Note: Now, modal height has been exceeded than before. And has gone
> out of windows height. And now our modal should scroll along with our
> windows scroll-bar on scrolling. (This is the common behavior of
> modal)

But, in my case, Modal is not getting scrolled properly. I just scroll down, and it scroll back automatically.

In short, I am facing a scrolling issue with my modal after adding dynamic content to my Bootstrap modal which change modal's dynamic height.

I have tried many solution but still failed to resolve this issue.

I have tried the following:

1. Adding overflow-y = auto
2. adding overflow-y = scroll

> Note: Even already, I have overflow-y to auto.

3. I have added following

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
```

But, still failed !

Finally, I'm here to post my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember to include your code when asking question Bilal. For now you could try adding `.modal-dialog-scrollable` alongside `.modal-dialog` in your HTML. Ths will add a scroll bar to the modal.

`class=" modal-dialogue modal-dialog-scrollable"`

Comment: Yes, sure! Next time I'll be careful about code while asking question. And thanks a lot for your kind answer. I have already tried this solution but failed to get proper results. Still, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Actually, when I open my Modal then its height is not more than windows (screen) height. And I also don't need any scrollbar on that time. But, after choosing an Image, I am showing a preview of that image. And then height of modal increased accordingly. And than on that time, I want my Modal to work with scrollbar.

Comment: OK so I am now questioning myself and wonder if `modal-dialogue` does not need to be present if also using `mobile-diaglue-scrollable`. Not 100% sure but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved by adding style="overflow:scroll" to the main div of the modal

```
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="overflow:scroll">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```